# Flutter - Amplify S3: How to read pdf files? "Pdf preview without downloading the file"

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, plugins, aws-amplify, pdf-viewer

in Flutter -  How to preview a pdf file from Amplify/S3 without downloading the file and when I click on the button?

when I click on the button to show the pdf preview.  in an easy way

I tried to download the file and then read it.